# Eclipse Java EE IDE not supporting javax.servlet package

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, jakarta-ee

I downloaded Eclipse Java EE IDE to build Java Web Applications (servlets and JSP pages). But it still is not supporting the `javax.servlet` package.

Why? What's the reason? Is there any plugin that I need to install?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to integrate a servlet container in Eclipse and associate it with your *Dynamic Web Project*. Eclipse doesn't ship with a servlet container by default. You need to download and install it separately. A widely used one is [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org). Just download the [ZIP](http://mirror.nyi.net/apache/tomcat/tomcat-6/v6.0.24/bin/apache-tomcat-6.0.24.zip) and extract it somewhere.

Then in Eclipse, go to the *Servers* view in the box at the right bottom. Then *Add* a new server where in you choose *Apache Tomcat 6* from the list and point the Tomcat root folder (there where you extracted it). Then you can select it from the *Target Runtime* dropdown during the *Dynamic Web Project* creation wizard. Or if you already have created one but didn't associate it with a server, then modify it in the *Targeted Runtimes* section of the project's properties. This way the server's libraries will be automagically added to the project's buildpath. That's finally also the whole point. The server is basically a **concrete implementation** of the *abstract* Servlet API. It has all the API libraries in its `/lib` folder.

Here's a [video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EOkN5IPoJVs) (which does it a bit differently than above described, but it's also sufficient) and here's a [text/screenshot tutorial](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/01/jsf-tutorial-with-eclipse-and-tomcat.html) (you can just skip the JSF part if that's not of interest yet).

Answer (score 6):

You probably need to create a Dynamic Web Project instead of a normal Java project.

Or you can add a server profile to your workspace, and then add the server runtime to a Java project's libraries.

1. To add the server profile, go to `Window -> Preferences -> Server -> Runtime Environments`.  Click `Add...`, choose the server type that you're using, specify the directory where that server is installed, and click `Finish`.
2. Now that you've added the server, you should be able to add it to the project as a library.  Right click the project, then go to `Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add Library -> Server Runtime`, choose the server you just added from the list, and click `Finish`.  This will make all the server's libraries available to your project.

Comment: I would like to go with adding server profile to my workspace. Could you please tell me how to add the server profile?

Comment: Sure, I added instructions for adding the server profile to your workspace, and then adding the server runtime libraries to your project.